# Plot the x-axis and y-axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am asked to plot the graph of a function in Matlab and I would like to add the x-axis and y-axis in the graph. But how can I achieve this?

Comment: Although this is not the right place for such questions (stackoverflow probably is), what you want is probably the functions `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

Comment: What do you mean "plot the x-axis and y-axis" do you want to plot labels, or data on the x and y axes? This question belongs on stackoverflow.com by the way.

Answer (score 2):

In Octave you can do:

```
x = [1:100]/10;
plot(x,sin(x),';legend;')
xlabel('xlabel')
ylabel('ylabel')
```

Comment: Matlab uses single quotes, not double

Comment: @LuisMendo: Thanks! I forgot to mention I was using Octave.